# Android calendar changing time changing date to today

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, timepicker

I am using `Calendar` and I am able to set date and get date for future. Assume that I have one `DatePickerDialog` which sets date for example **15-09-2016** and I have one `TimePickerDialog` which sets hour for example : **22:30**

My problem is when I use `DatePickerDialog` and set date to : **15-09-2016** it's ok. But, then I use `TimePickerDialog` and try to change time, `Calendar's` date is changing to today (**27-07-2016**).

But if I use `TimePickerDialog` firstly then use `DatePickerDialog` there is no issue and I am able to set date : **15-09-2016 22:30**

I checked Google and Stackoverflow and looked suggested questions when creating this question but i didnt see anything.

My `DatePickerDialog` :

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=
   new DatePickerDialog(thisActivity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
          mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
          mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
          mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
          SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy kk:mm",Locale.getDefault());
          String datetime = dateformat.format(mCalendarAlarm.getTime());
          alarmDate.setText(datetime);
          }}, mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.MONTH),
          mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mCalendarAlarm.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.show();
```

My `TimePickerDialog` :

```
TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
int hour = mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(thisActivity,mPickerTheme, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
   @Override
   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
       mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,selectedHour);
       mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,selectedMinute);
       alarmDialogTime.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", selectedHour, selectedMinute));
       }}, hour, minute, true);
mTimePicker.show();
```

When declaring `Calendar` :

```
mCalendarAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendarAlarm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
```

So how can I solve this issue , is there a way or you guys meet this issue before. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using same calendar object  `mCalendarAlarm` for both `TimePicker` and `DatePicker`. Try to use different object of `Calendar` class for both pickers.

For example:

`mCalendarAlarm` for `DatePicker` and create new `Calendar` object `mTimeAlarm` for `TimePicker`

If you have multiple init `mCalendarAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();` delete unnecessary inits.

Comment: I beat issue by deleting unnecessary `mCalendarAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();` . I had multiple `mCalendarAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();` init . Deleted all of them and I init `Calendar` only one time. Your answer was helped me i am working continuously like 3 days(sleep ,eat ,code loop) maybe i must take some break. Thanks.